# Django: Two buttons save on one page

Tags: python, django, forms, backend

I have problem (django app) with buttons on one page. Buttons on bottom of the page are not working, and all buttons on top are working good. On bottom only save button doesn't work.
Below is my code in template.

Here is my buttons on **top**:

```
{% block top_menu %}
    {% get_obj_perms user for current_calendar as "perm_list" %}
    <form action="{% if post.pk %}{% url 'event_edit' post.pk %}{% else %}{% url 'event_create' %}{% endif %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset {% if 'can_edit_posts' not in perm_list %}disabled="disabled"{% endif %}>
          <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="" />
          <ul class="btn-group">
            <li><a href="{{ back_url|default:"/" }}"><span class="button"><i class="icon-left"></i>Back</span></a></li>
            {% if 'can_edit_posts' in perm_list %}
                <li><input class="button" id="save" type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="bottom_button"></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="{{ back_url|default:"/" }}"><i class="icon-cancel-circled"></i>Discard Changes</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if 'can_delete_posts' in perm_list and post.pk %}
                <li><a class="button" href="{% url 'event_delete' post.pk %}"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Delete</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock top_menu %}
```

Here is my buttons on **bottom**:

```
{% block bottom_menu %}
    {% get_obj_perms user for current_calendar as "perm_list" %}
    <form action="{% if post.pk %}{% url 'event_edit' post.pk %}{% else %}{% url 'event_create' %}{% endif %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <fieldset {% if 'can_edit_posts' not in perm_list %}disabled="disabled"{% endif %}>
          <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="" />
          <ul class="btn-group">
            <li><a href="{{ back_url|default:"/" }}"><span class="button"><i class="icon-left"></i>Back</span></a></li>
            {% if 'can_edit_posts' in perm_list %}
                <li><input class="button" id="save" type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="bottom_button"></li>
                <li><a class="button" href="{{ back_url|default:"/" }}"><i class="icon-cancel-circled"></i>Discard Changes</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if 'can_delete_posts' in perm_list and post.pk %}
                <li><a class="button" href="{% url 'event_delete' post.pk %}"><i class="icon-trash"></i>Delete</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock bottom_menu %}
```

I recived django errors when I used bottom buttons:

```
status
This field is required.
calendar
This field is required.
pub_date
This field is required.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any JS errors appearing in console tab ?

Comment: can you tell us more about what "not working" means?

Comment: @ChrisCurvey I recived django error, please checḱ my edit

Comment: @AbijithMg  I recived django error, please checḱ my edit

Comment: status, calendar and pub_date are empty in the bottom form. So when you submit the same, it will raise field required validation error.

Comment: @AbijithMg is the way to solve this?

Comment: Send values for status, calendar and pub_date in the bottom form.